# Determine the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-kx^2} \ dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Determine the limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-kx^2} \ dx.$$

Using DCT I have that if $f_k(x) = e^{-kx^2} $, then $f_k \to 0$ since $e^{-kx^2} = \frac{1}{e^{kx^2}}$ which will tend to zero for large $k$.

So by DCT $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-kx^2} \ dx  = \int_{0}^\infty 0 \ dx = 0.$$

The integral indeed seems to be $0$, but I’m not sure if I’ve used the DCT correctly here?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring about half of DCT. What does the theorem say, exactly?

Comment: A better and simpler way in my opinion would be to evaluate the integral first. It will be equal to $\frac12 \sqrt{\frac \pi k }$. Taking the limit, we can conclude that it's $0$.

Answer (score 1):

To apply DCT you have to produce a dominating integrable function. In this case $0\leq f_k(x)\leq e^{-x^{2}}$ for all $x$ and $k$. Since $e^{-x^{2}}$ is integrable we can apply DCT.

Using the fact that $e^{x^{2}}>1+x^{2}$ check that $e^{-x^{2}} < \frac  1{1+x^{2}}$. Can you show that $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ is integrable?

Comment: But $e^{-x^2}$ doesn’t seem to be very easy to integerate?

Comment: @JimingLe I have edited.

Comment: @JimingLe You may enjoy [these proofs](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf) of $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$.